Is it possible to update string formed with variable after initialization (JS)
Is there a way to force a string declared with a concatenated variable to update once the variable itself is updated?
For example the current behavior is:
let test = "hello world";
let string = `blah blah ${test}`;

console.log(string); // output: "blah blah hello world";

test = "blah";

console.log(string); // output: "blah blah hello world", desired output: "blah blah blah";

That was just an example of the question but in reality I need it for dynamic text used in multiple strings within a large object that gets declared at the start of my program. Updating them all manually would be tedious and inefficient so if there is another way of solving this please let me know.
var obj = { ... 
            example1: `hello world ${dynamicText}`, 
            example2: `blah blah ${dynamicText} blah`,
            example3: `test ${dynamicText}`,
          ... }


No, strings (including template literals) are immutable. Create a function that returns the string if you need it more dynamic

The easiest way would be to use an object and methods that builds the string.
